# Как можно скомпилировать проект JAVA

Tags: java, компиляция

Как скомпилировать проект `Java` так, чтобы не было видно его исходный код или чтобы он был в `EXE`-формате?

Comment: Видно исходный код где? Что значит exe? Какая платформа? Windows? Дополните ответ, что вам надо тут сделать, что вы пытались и что не вышло.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-executable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855937/how-can-i-convert-java-to-exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516399/how-do-i-create-an-exe-for-a-java-program https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906317/how-to-convert-the-java-project-to-exe  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332548/running-a-java-program-as-an-exe-in-windows-without-jre-installed видать вас в поисковике забанили

Comment: 1)На машине пользователя должна быть установлена JRE не ниже той, которую используете вы.
2)Простейший путь это создать артефакт, во вкладке File->Poject Structure
3)И скомпилировать его при помощи Build.
4)Если ваше приложение консольное, то запустить его из бинарника(.bat)
Всё это актуально для IDEA, про другие ИДЕ не знаю, и делать из .jar .exe не рекомендую.

Comment: Возможно вы имеете ввиду обфускацию кода?